# Creating and Using a SWC File - Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-builder, swc

So I'm really confused on how to create, and use, a SWC file. I understand that a SWC file can be created to hold multiple assets. Basically, my code setup is the following:

- c_Test.as - all testing of classes/fla files is done here
- c_Test.fla - contains a few visual objects used/tested in c_Test.as
- Class.as - class referenced multiple times in c_Test.as
- Class1.fla - contains an important bitmap that is loaded into c_Test.as

So what I need to do is create a SWC file to be used in other projects; this is going to be the base of a multitude of other large projects, and I don't want to have to continuously copy and paste code into different folders. I am using Flash Builder 4.

So far, I went to publish settings in Flash CS6 in my c_Test.fla file and checked off Export SWF and Export SWC. What does this do? Has this created my SWC file?

I need to be able to access, from any random project, both Class.as, and Class1.fla.

**Edit**

So to clarify, cw_Test.fla is just a testing copy of the actual main fla file. I don't need this included in my swc. I just Exported my Class1.fla to SWf and SWC, and set a library path to the folder containing Class.as. Is this all I need to do to access both of these files from any project? (Besides importing them into any file I need them in).

Comment: Re-using Main has troubles, as each Flash CS project has its own `Main` class, with its timeline, assets and other stuff. You might be able to reuse a set of classes if you do package them, check that they don't depend on the remainder of the project, and try exporting the SWC that'll contain only that package.

Comment: Re-named some files for convenience. Could you take a look again and tell me if I should do something different?